# Unable to find Android device with SnapdragonProfiler

Tags: android, adb, qualcomm

I was unable to get the SnapdragonProfiler tool, running on MacOS Ventura, to recognize the connected Samsung Galaxy S21 device. Even though `adb devices` shows that the device is indeed recognized and connected.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve this issue:

1. Verify that the device you are connecting has a Snapdragon chipset
2. Install the latest `adb` and `NDK` builds via Android Studio
3. Inside SnapdragonProfiler, go to File > Settings > Android
4. Provide the paths to the directories that *contain* `adb` and the specific build of `NDK`, not those builds themselves. For me, this was `<my user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` (for `adb`) and `<my user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk` (for NDK; specific build number is inside this directory).